# Запрос на вставку NULL php

Tags: php, sql, база-данных

Как сделать запрос на вставку NULL?
Точнее как сделать это через переменную  `$date_contract_finish`

```
if ($_GET['date_contract_finish'] == ''){
  $date_contract_finish = NULL;
}else{
  $date_contract_finish = $_GET['date_contract_finish'];
}
$sql = "UPDATE project_registry SET 
        date_contract_finish = '$date_contract_finish' 
         WHERE id = '$id'"
```

В итоге вставляется пустая строка, а необходимо вставить null.

Comment: а null это не пустая строка ?

Comment: ага, понял вопрос

Comment: я бы на вашем месте озадачился валидацией данных по крайней мере, а то передача значения `1970-01-01' #` вам обновит всю таблицу целиком.

Comment: это как если бы я делал обычный запрос в субд
update project_registry set date_contract_finish = NULL where id = 32;

Comment: честно говоря я и пытаюсь победить проблему, когда при пустой строке в input у меня в поле дата уходит 1900-01-01 вместо NULL

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
if ($_GET['date_contract_finish'] == ''){
  $date_contract_finish = "NULL";
}else{
  $date_contract_finish = "'" . $_GET['date_contract_finish'] ."'";
}

$sql = "UPDATE project_registry SET 
        date_contract_finish = $date_contract_finish
         WHERE id = '$id'"
```

Comment: я так пробовал, и ".$date_contract_finish." тоже пробовал, не выходит

Comment: @ИгорьТюлькин  кавычка там лишняя в запросе а так вариант рабочий, только не менее дырявый чем ваш код в вопросе

Comment: так скажите как лучше)

Comment: да, кавычку не заметил, код пправил

Comment: ну а что бы он не был дырявым, нужно использовать хотя бы PDO

Comment: спасибо, изучу что это

Answer (score 1):

Используйте механизм `prepared statements`. Что `PDO` что `mysqli` корректно передают NULL через prepared statements. И, что существенно важнее, закроете открытую дыру для sql-инъекции.

```
$stmt = $pdo->prepare("UPDATE project_registry SET 
    date_contract_finish = :date_contract_finish
     WHERE id = :id");
$stmt->execute([
    'date_contract_finish' => empty($_GET['date_contract_finish']) ? null : $_GET['date_contract_finish'],
    'id' => $id,
]);
```

Если вам действительно не нужно валидировать формат. Хотя скорее всего вам сперва нужно проверить, что вам передали что-то похожее на дату.